# Android Studio add image on menu

Tags: android

I would like to insert an image in the menu background, but in the properties of the menu is not such action. How I do this?
This is the menu code (it's very simple):

```
menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/MENU_1"
    android:title="Gioca"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/MENU_2"
    android:title="Esci"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this in the xml:
 `android:icon="@drawable/your_icon_for_menu"`